# How to gain access to specific windows and controllers on an unfamiliar desktop app

Tags: pywinauto

I'm new to GUI testing, so i'm sorry if the question is a little too simple, but i could not find an answer on other related discussions.
I'm trying to automate test for an desktop application that i have no access to it's code, hence no way to know the internal structure and the "path" to specific controllers or windows.

Following the "quick start guide", i was able to start the application, and even to get a valid response for app.top_window().

But that's about it.. i can't seem to be able to get a list of the available windows or components that are under the top window.
Tried to use print_control_identifiers(), and got a Match error - could not find keys in dict dict_keys.

I read that there is an option to look for a window using "best match" technique, but since i don't know the name of any window or controller - i don't know what to write in it in order to get something that i can use..

my code:

```
import pywinauto as PW
app = PW.application.Application().Start("PQS.Client.exe")
handle = app.top_window()
x = app.handle.print_control_identifiers()
```

To make long story short - i'm stuck.. so any pointer or help would be much appreciated..

Comment: `app.top_window()` returns not a handle! It's `WindowSpecification` object. Do you mean [this guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html)?

Comment: `app.handle` is equivalent to `app.window(best_match="handle")` so this statement doesn't use `handle` variable, but creates another window specification that assumes "handle" is the most probable window title (which is not).